# Why does systemd not respect timeout?

Tags: systemd

For some unexplained reason stopping `lvm2-monitor.service` takes a long time on my server.

`systemd` says:

```
# systemctl show lvm2-monitor.service -p TimeoutStopUSec
TimeoutStopUSec=1min 30s
```

But when stopping the server I get:

```
A stop job is running for Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling (4min 2s / 5min 20s)
```

The 5min 20s started as 1min 30s, but was adjusted up.

Why does `systemd` not respect the 1m30s?

Is there a way I can tell `systemd` not to give in to intimidation from LVM2, but instead stay strong saying "Time is up. You are going down"?

Comment: This comment from a Github issue indicates a non-standard dependency/ordering for LVM: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3912#issuecomment-239127751 . Would appreciate if someone could turn this into a proper answer; I'm not confident that I can address this comprehensively.

Comment: @Haxiel, I think you could just post this link (and quote the relevant github comment in your answer). I would consider it as a proper answer. This github comment in your link seems comprehensive enough.